# Сильно искажается изображение

Tags: php

есть 2 пикчи:
[image]

[image]

я хочу их соединить

```php
$tim = imagecreatefrompng("pics/tim.png");
$meme = imagecreatefromjpeg("pics/vk.jpg");
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($tim), imagesy($tim));
imagecopyresampled($image, $meme, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($tim), imagesy($tim) - 25, imagesx($meme), imagesy($meme));
imagecopyresized($image, $tim, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($tim), imagesy($tim), imagesx($tim), imagesy($tim));
imagepng($image, "pics/pic.png");
```

но получается такое:
[image]

c куком всё впорядке, а фон пострадал

как добиться наилучшего качества фона?

Answer (score 1):

```
imagepng ( resource $image [, mixed $to = NULL [, int $quality = -1 [, int $filters = -1 ]]] ) : bool
```

Попробуйте изменить quality в 0, скорее всего оно по умолчанию установлено в 9 у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранил файлы, запустил скрипт:

[image: результат]

**не такой же**, как у вас. Версию PHP и конфигурацию php.ini для [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gd-info.php) в студию!

Comment: хостинг для нищебродов, вытащить php.ini не могу, версия пхп: 5.6.36-0+deb8u1

Comment: Попробуйте через веб <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: там очень много букв

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3gzeE3z2 @daniel-protopopov

Comment: Трудно сказать, будем-с ждать если кто-то еще знает, тогда я удалю свой ответ. У себя тестировал на OpenServer PHP v7.2 x64. Сменил на версию PHP 5.6, запустил через консоль - результат тот же. Вероятно у вас в действии установки введенные хостингом, но по конфигу не знаю какие настройки на это влияют.

Comment: @OverPie, попробуйте использовать `Imagick`.

Comment: @lets-say-pie, хостинг не поддерживает Imagick(